# Как поставить уведомление о приходе заявки на чужом сайте?

Tags: javascript

Есть сайт, я там авторизуюсь. В окно приходит сообщение. Чтобы его увидеть, страничку приходится перезагружать (как то разработчик не продумал). Ну черт с ним, ставлю автообновление страницы. Но при появлении нового сообщения, хотел бы получить звуковое уведомление. Как и с помощью чего возможно такое реализовать?
 Я видел, как в хроме нажимают F12 и правят "код страницы" я как понимаю это работа проводится на JavaScript. Поэтому у меня такое ощущение, что это не сложно реализовать.

Comment: Если знаете HTML и JavaScript, можете написать расширение для Chrome, которое будет анализировать DOM страницы с сообщениями и отправлять уведомления, если есть новые.

Comment: Ничего кроме java я не знаю.  Поэтому хотел бы как можно более простое решение. Самым простым кажется возможность написать какой нибудь javascript

Comment: Я так понимаю, на javaScrit можно узнавать, что пришло новое сообщение, но есть проблема с тем как уведомить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через F12 можно исправить код страницы, но проблема в том, что все исправления пропадут после перезагрузки. Единственный вариант - написать расширение для браузера. Не знаю как для хрома, но для мозилы есть https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ - простое дополнение, которое позволит встроить свой код в сайт. Ну а как обработать само уведомление, уже от сайта зависит.

**Update:**
Чтобы найти найти сообщение на странице, скопируйте его селектор (пример на картинке), потом:

```
if (document.querySelector('скопированный селектор')) // проверит есть ли элемент на странице
{
    // тут вывести звук
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему как обработать уведомление зависит от сайта?  Сайт в том то и дело что не обрабатывает ничего.  Делаю перезагрузку, вижу что сообщение новое есть и всё. Никаких уведомлений нет.

Comment: Нужно каким-то образом узнать о том, что уведомление пришло, это уже зависит от реализации сайта. Самый простой вариант, просто распарсить страницу в поисках окна с уведомлением. Сложно ответить не видя сайт.

Comment: Да бесполезно сайт скидывать потому что функционал скрыл пока не авторизуешься. Регистрация  вроде платная. На работе эту гадость используют.  Хотелось бы еще узнать, а чем парсят страницы? Мне парсер понадобится в любом случае написать, чтобы с одной страницы, поля в другую копировать. Поэтому можно двуз зайцев одним выстрелом.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Из либ для парсинга использую на php - simplehtmldom, на noedjs - cheerio.

Comment: Конечно для меня всё это выглядит очень абстрактно , но вроде общая логика мне понятна.

Comment: Ну я как понимаю расширешие понадобится всё равно? Ибо любой код страницы , очистится после обновления.

Comment: Да, без расширения никак

Answer (score 1):

Если интересует именно звуковое уведомление, то это можно сделать так

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://noisefx.ru/noise_base/zvon/01070.mp3');
audioElement.play();
```

Comment: Постойте постойте.. Я даже не знаю, что это и куда писать. Меня пока интересует теория.  Тут из кода я интуитивно понимаю, что создаете переменную куда грузится аудио файл. и метод для воспроизведения. Но где это писать? и в какой момент это должно проигрываться, т.е. как мне определить вообще, что новое сообщение пришло?

Comment: Я вам написал в комментариях под вашим вопросом, что вам нужно написать расширение для браузера, которое будет анализировать DOM нужной вам страницы и определять есть ли новые сообщения.
Приведённый мной код создаёт на странице новый элемент `<audio src='http://noisefx.ru/noise_base/zvon/01070.mp3></audio>'`, с которым потом и работает.

Comment: ааа,. все понял. Ладно..так уж и быть. значит расширение.  На чем их пишут по стандарту?

Comment: Как писал выше, для создания расширения используются `HTML` и `JavaScript`. На просторах сети есть множество руководств по созданию расширений.